# Declaring Multiple Object with Different Names

Tags: java, class, loops, object

The number of objects that are created differ depending on user input, so how can I declare the following with a for loop in Java?

```
    MicroStep darkCalibMicro0 = new MicroStep();
    MicroStep darkCalibMicro1 = new MicroStep();
    MicroStep darkCalibMicro2 = new MicroStep();
    MicroStep darkCalibMicro3 = new MicroStep();
    MicroStep darkCalibMicro4 = new MicroStep();
    MicroStep darkCalibMicro5 = new MicroStep();
```

These can't be hardcoded, they have to be generated based on the size that the user inputs.

Comment: You need a list `List<MicroStep>` or an array `MicroStep[]`.

Comment: Two options available in java for storing a collection of items is an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) (for when the length is known and constant) and [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) (for when the length is unknown or variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. After I read wrong the question (my english is not the best):

What you want to do is an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), you can get that done like that:

Let's say the user input 40.

```
Integer userInput = 40;
ArrayList<MicroStep> microStepList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {
microStepList.add(new MicroStep());
}
```

That way you'll get an List with size of 40, with 40 MicroStep on it. Then if you want to access to any of these objects you can do:

```
MicroStep m = microStepList.get(i);
```

Comment: `map.put(3, new MicroStep())` rather than `list.set(3, new MicroStep())` or `array[3] = new MicroStep()`?

Comment: A `HashMap` is overkill if you just need a list of items, not an association of key => value.

Comment: Well, maybe. He said: "These can't be hardcoded, they have to be generated based on the size that the user inputs.", I guess he was meaning that the user can input 0, 500, 324 and that'll be alright.

Comment: @Yayotrón you can just keep adding items to an `ArrayList`: `ArrayList<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>(); for( int i = 0; i < input; ++i ) list.Add( new Foo() );` Then you have `input` number of `Foo`s: `list.get(0)` through `list.get(input-1)`

Comment: @Yayotrón according to the poster's question, the poster seems to have a solid sequence starting from zero in mind: `darkCalibMicro0` to `darkCalibMicro5`.

Comment: You all are alright. I read wrong the question, I edited my answer.

Comment: MicroStep[] steps = new MicroStep[QRData.number_steps];
  for(int i = 0; i < QRData.number_steps; i++){
   steps[i] = new MicroStep();
   steps[i].setTitle(btn_instructions.get(i));
   steps[i].setDescription(instruction_text.get(i));
   steps[i].setInstructionVideo(videos.get(i));
   steps[i].setAudioInstruction(audio.get(i));
   //System.out.println("steps[i]: " + steps[i]);
  }

Comment: The above syntax ended up working, thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

@Yayotrón answer is correct. Here there's one Java 8 way of doing it:

```
List<MicroStep> list = 
    IntStream.range(0, userInput)
    .mapToObj(i -> new MicroStep())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```